# Do I need to stay in Title & Action Safe areas for Youtube

Tags: animation, video, adobe-after-effects

I'm creating a short promo video for a mobile app using After Effects. It's going to be used only on YouTube. I'm trying to show the actual layout of the app, but the menus are all along the left and top edges.

Do I need to worry about making all the content in the Title and Action Safe areas, if it's only going to be on YouTube?

Answer (score 1):

I've had no issues with this and completely ignore the areas. Of course it doesn't take that much work for you to do an export, upload it to youtube, and see for yourself. Might depend on what size video you're making for example and how you export it.

Answer (score 1):

The only time you need to be worried about title/action safe margins are when a piece is going to be played back on a TV. If it is going to to on YouTube then nothing will be cropped, unless somebody is somehow streaming to their TV from YouTube.

Comment: it might make a difference on a mobile device.

Comment: I've never seen a YouTube video cropped on a mobile device...

Comment: well i have, anyway the cropping is not really the reason for safe areas. No panel has really cropped anhthing in 10 years. Its just still sane to follow this rule, edges may be far off, viewer may be off center etc... so margins are a good deal anyway. its allways potentially a bad odea to be pn the exact edge.